# Problems re-writing a plist

Tags: ios, plist, overwrite

Ok I've been having issues overwriting the contents of a plist that I've created. I've included all the code below:

So in my first view controller I create the plist and then I update it with the update directory method. Ok my issue shows up in the overwrite plist area. My idea is to create a dictionary from the file and then add/overwrite certain keys then re-write the file. This code allows me to write objects with no errors, but when I try to read the values from the file I get null for all the new values.

Update: Code works now. I needed to change the Area_#_Total_L to Area_#_Total_L.text. This is because there are a limited number of items you can add to a dictionary (see answer one for object types).

**Creating Directory:**

```
-(void)Create_Directory {

    // Create File Location

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Temporary_Variable_Repository.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Temporary_Variable_Repository" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
    }

    // End
        NSLog(@"path in ViewController: %@", path);
    DataLocation = path;

}
```

**Updating Directory:**

```
-(void)Update_Directory {

    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: DataLocation];

    //All Variables that need to be saved need to be listed here
    //Creating Directory Example
    //[data setObject:@"Directory" forKey:@"Key"];

    NSLog(@"Saving Variables...");

    int Temp = [[data valueForKey:@"-Run_ID"] intValue]+1;
    NSLog(@"Run ID: %d", Temp);

    [data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Temp] forKey:@"-Run_ID"];
    [data setObject:Date_Time forKey:@"-Run_Date_Time"];
    [data setObject:@"In Progress" forKey:@"-Run_Status"];
    [data setObject:@"ViewController" forKey:@"-Run_Chapter"];
    [data setObject:@"0" forKey:@"-Run_Page"];
    [data setObject:@"User" forKey:@"-User"];
    [data setObject:@"0001" forKey:@"-User_Device"];

    //End

    BOOL result = [data writeToFile: DataLocation atomically:YES];
    NSLog(result ? @"Yes" : @"No");    
}
```

**Overwrite Plist**

```
NSLog(@"Saving Variables...");

//Verify the variables are updated prior to transfer
[self RefreshAreaLabels];

//Close keypad
[self closeKeypad];


//Prep next screen for loading
RoofSlope *NewView = [[RoofSlope alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

//Send location of Temp Var Rep
NewView.DataLocation_Pass2 = DataLocation_Pass1;

//Create a copy of Temp Var Rep
NSMutableDictionary *ViewController_Reference = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataLocation_Pass1];

//Write variables
[ViewController_Reference setObject:@"AtticArea" forKey:@"-Run_Chapter"];

[ViewController_Reference setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Area_1_Length_TF.text] forKey:@"Area_1_Length"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_1_Width_TF.text forKey:@"Area_1_Width"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_1_Total_L.text forKey:@"Area_1_Total"];

[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_2_Length_TF.text forKey:@"Area_2_Length"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_2_Width_TF.text forKey:@"Area_2_Width"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_2_Total_L.text forKey:@"Area_2_Total"];

[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_3_Length_TF.text forKey:@"Area_3_Length"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_3_Width_TF.text forKey:@"Area_3_Width"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_3_Total_L.text forKey:@"Area_3_Total"];

[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_4_Length_TF.text forKey:@"Area_4_Length"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_4_Width_TF.text forKey:@"Area_4_Width"];
[ViewController_Reference setObject:Area_4_Total_L.text forKey:@"Area_4_Total"];

 [ViewController_Reference setObject:@"TEST" forKey:@"-Run_ID"];

[ViewController_Reference setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[TotalAreaValue_L.text doubleValue]] forKey:@"Total_Area"];

//Debug
NSLog(@"Area_1_Length: %@", [ViewController_Reference valueForKey:@"Area_1_Length"]);
NSLog(@"_Run_ID: %@", [ViewController_Reference valueForKey:@"-Run_ID"]);

//Update Variable Repository
//This writes the updated variables to the plist
BOOL result = [ViewController_Reference writeToFile: DataLocation_Pass1 atomically:YES];    

NSLog(result ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Answer (score 0):

As apple document:

> If the array’s contents are all property list objects (NSString,
>   NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects), the file written by this
>   method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method
>   arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method
>   initWithContentsOfFile:. This method recursively validates that all
>   the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the
>   file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects,
>   since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

Make sure all your objects are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects).

`[NSNumber numberWithInt:Temp]` may be the problem.

Comment: I'll verify my item types, but I don't think my issue lies in "numberWithInt." Because that value is displayed via NSLog and is correct in both viewcontrollers. All values from viewcontroller one I believe are saved correctly. I checked them with NSLog statments. The problem is when I add new objects and the try to overwrite the file the new objects don't show. Instead the file still shows the values set in viewcontroller one.

Comment: Ok update solved the issue. You were right....kinda the problem was when I was trying to transfer Area_#_Total_L. The problem was I was trying to save a label to a dictionary. Instead it needs to be Area_#_Total_L.text Thanks for your help.